# Can't import javafx.media in IntelliJ project

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javafx

In my main file, when I try to import `javafx.media packages`, I receive this message:

> `Cannot resolve symbol 'media'`

I've added the dependency to my **module-info.java**, but the dependency is in red with the message `Module not found: javafx.media`.

I've also added the dependency to my pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
    <artifactId>javafx-media</artifactId>
    <version>17.0.0.1</version>
</dependency>
```

But `javafx-media` is in red here too, with the message:

> `Dependency 'org.openjfx:javafx-media:17.0.0.1' not found`

No clue on how to fix this!

Comment: try pressing ctrl+shift+a and then run this command "mvn clean package"

Comment: @VasanthSubramanian I'm running MacOS and IntelliJ, so I'm not sure what this is supposed to do.

Comment: sorry, try pressing CTRL twice and run the command

Comment: Got it. Did that and after completing, the issue persists.

Comment: Are you using the javafx-maven-plugin? If not, try adding that plugin and seeing if it solves your issue (see https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/ ; _JavaFX and IntelliJ → Modular with Maven_).

Comment: @Slaw Probably a dumb question but how do you add plugins to an already existing project?

Comment: are you behind any firewall? Is there any proxy configuration required? because i added the dependency in my pom.xml and it worked

Comment: @VasanthSubramanian No, I'm on my home network. Can I ask what exactly you entered into your pom.xml?

Comment: i added the same dependency you mentioned in your question in the pom.xml file

Comment: "_how do you add plugins to an already existing project_" – By editing the POM file. Check out the [POM Reference](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Plugins) for general syntax. See the [javafx-maven-plugin](https://github.com/openjfx/javafx-maven-plugin#usage) README for specific usage of that plugin. Though just to be clear, I don't know if adding this plugin will fix your problem.

Comment: the version looks fishy - if that ever existed, it was an emergency release just after initial GA, the current stable 17 is something like 17.0.2 (last number probably higher) - note that there is only a single "0.", not two

Comment: @Slaw Okay. I've been using that the entire time, then. I had the relevant lines in the pom file from the start, and it wasn't working.

Comment: @kleopatra I made that fix but I'm getting the same problem